# Trying to read a text file wtih pandas. Data is text wrapped, can't get pandas to split into seperate columns

Tags: python, pandas

Totally new to python. The chunk of data up until the semicolon is one item. Each number separated by a space is a attribute that needs to go into it's own column:

```
        1 164477000 73449000 0 0 512 306 396173.0 512 10 6 0 0 0 1 10 10 0  N 80.110001 
          219 11.062500 0.069141 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
          0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 NA NA NA NA NA 3.472138 NA 0.678533 NA NA 
          NA NA NA 95.849327 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
          NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
          NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
          NA NA NA NA ;
        2 200368000 83175000 0 0 318 87 167005.0 318 991 6 0 0 0 1 991 991 0  N 142.179993 
          231 1.125000 0.007031 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
          0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 100.000000 
          NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
          NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
          NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ;
```

Here is the code that I've tried. It all just gets sent to one column.

**test = pd.read_fwf("file.txt",
header=None, skiprows=41, skipfooter=45, colspecs='infer', widths=None, delimiter=r";"]**

Comment: Use `read_csv`, and make the delimiter or (`sep`) a space. You get an extra column with just semi-colons, that you can remove once you've read the data. Any other arguments are *not* necessary.

Comment: You say "The chunk of data up until the semicolon is one item". But practically, I assume it is one *line* instead? (It only becomes one or more items one you parse it.)

Comment: There is the `lineterminator` parameter of `read_csv()` that may work here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv it does have the caveat "Only valid with C parser." and I'm not sure what that means, so YMMV.

Comment: @JNevill The `lineterminator` needs to be one character. Here, it would (apparently) need to be a semi-colon plus a newline character, making at least two characters.

Comment: @9769953 While the entry is multiple lines in the flat file, OP wishes to treat it as a single line up to the semicolon. Essentially the record delimiter is a semicolon, not a new-line character (if I'm understanding correctly).

Comment: @JNevill Since the OP mentions they want "each number separated by a space [...] into it's own column", I read that as the semi-colon to be ignored, and the newline simply as is. Unless the newline was added by the OP here in the question, but is not in the input file. I put a question about that in an earlier comment.

Comment: @JNevill fwiw that version of the docs is _ancient_ here's the latest! https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html .. it's probably reasonable to just have an extra string column with the semicolon, use `\n` as the line delimiter, and throw it away after loading

Comment: Instead of a space for the delimiter, you can also use a regular expression to account for multiple spaces: `sep=r'\s+'` will use multiple spaces as separator between column items.

Comment: Yes @JNevill. The record delimiter is a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining all the comments, [Pandas `.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can probably load this for you with a few options

- `header=None` (no header provided)
- `delimiter=r"\s+"` runs of whitespace of any kind are one contiguous delimiter
- `lineterminator=";"` data lines don't end at `\n`, but continue to each `;`

I've used an [`io.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to directly load from the given text in an interpreter, but this shouldn't be necessary if you have a file you can read from instead (just pass the filename or a reference to it) .. if you find you need to clean up the input data, you can load the file contents as a string and then make a `StringIO` (for example, I `.strip()`'d off the newlines I'd added to clean up the input)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = """
... 1 164477000 73449000 0 0 512 306 396173.0 512 10 6 0 0 0 1 10 10 0  N 80.110001
...   219 11.062500 0.069141 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
...   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 NA NA NA NA NA 3.472138 NA 0.678533 NA NA
...   NA NA NA 95.849327 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
...   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
...   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
...   NA NA NA NA ;
... 2 200368000 83175000 0 0 318 87 167005.0 318 991 6 0 0 0 1 991 991 0  N 142.179993
...   231 1.125000 0.007031 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
...   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 100.000000
...   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
...   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
...   NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ;
... """.strip()  # throw out empty lines added to improve display above
>>> from io import StringIO  # make the data block a file-like for this example
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None, delimiter=r"\s+", lineterminator=";")
>>> df
   0          1         2    3    4    5    6         7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   ...  109  110  111 112  113 114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123
0    1  164477000  73449000    0    0  512  306  396173.0  512   10    6    0    0    0    1  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   \n  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    2  200368000  83175000    0    0  318   87  167005.0  318  991    6    0    0    0    1  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[2 rows x 124 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, with some tweaking to the rest of the file I was able to get this to work! Very new to python so I appreciate your thorough explanation!

Comment: @Podasaurus anytime! if this or other Answers solve your Question, please mark them as the Answer with the check to the left! alternatively, if you needed to make a lot of tweaks, please add your own Answer!